# WinDBGとフリーズについて

Tags: windows

***現状***
・不定期で、Windows10のデスクトップパソコンがフリーズします

---

**試したこと**
・「イベント ビューアー」を確認してみたのですが、エラーが多過ぎて、フリーズの原因が分かりません
・Kernel-Power 41 の直前のエラーも毎回異なります
・そもそもここにフリーズの原因が記録されているかどうかも分かりません

---

**質問**
・WinDBGを使用すれば、フリーズの原因を突き止められますか？
・フリーズ発生しても、ダンプファイルには記録されない？

---

**質問背景**
・今日4回フリーズしたのですが、下記ダンプファイルの更新日時は何れも2日前になっていたので、フリーズ内容は(クラッシュとは異なるので)記録されないのかと疑問に思いました
・ダンプファイルに記録されなければ、WinDBGで解析することはできない？？

> C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP\
>   C:\Windows\Minidump\

・[WinDBG をインストールしたら、下記サイトを参考にシンボルファイルパスの設定をし、ダンプを開いてみてください](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14164107564)

Comment: Kernel-Power 41は「KP41」と呼ばれて、数年前に話題になりました。色々な原因(ハード/OS共にあり)で発生するので原因を特定するのが難しく、原因が多様なので様々な解決方法が検索できてしまいます。製造元に問い合わせるのが得策かもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

フリーズ現象が発生したタイミングで、キーボード クラッシュさせれば、そのフリーズ現象を解析するためのダンプ ファイルは採取できる。
フリーズ現象のダンプ調査は、BSOD のダンプ調査に比べはるかに難しいけど、根性出して絞り込んでいけば、大抵の場合は特定できる。
問題はその根性があるかどうかだけ。
ちなみに、フリーズ現象の調査で採取するダンプの種類は、「完全メモリダンプ」でないと有効な調査はできません。

あと、提示されている知恵袋でダンプ解析を提案しているのは私です。ｗｗｗｗ

Comment: 「完全メモリダンプ」取得するためには、予めレジストリ編集が必要ですか？　なるべくレジストリを触りたくないのですが、例えば「Debug Diagnostic Tool」で「Full userdump」を選択すれば、同じ「完全メモリダンプ」を取得できますか？

Comment: レジストリをいぢらなくても、「完全メモリダンプ」を採取できる (場合もある)。
まずは下記サイトを参考に、UI 上からの「完全メモリダンプ」設定を行ってみてください。


完全メモリダンプを設定する方法
https://community.sophos.com/kb/ja-jp/111474

Comment: レジストリ編集に関する説明は、「完全メモリダンプ」オプションがドロップダウンメニューに表示されない場合に対する話なのですね。必ず必要だと勘違いしていました(実際には必要かもしれませんが…)

Comment: ちなみに、メモリや CPU 等ハードウェアの不具合でフリーズすることは、基本的に考えられない。
メモリや CPU の不具合だったらフリーズではなく BSOD が発生するはずだし、そもそも PC が起動できなくなる。
(フリーズやブルースクリーンの発生原因がハードウェアによるもの主張される人は、ブルースクリーンがなぜ起きるのか、そのメカニズムをきちんと理解できていない。)

Comment: プルダウンで「完全メモリダンプ」選択後、反映させるためパソコンを自分で再起動しました。その後フリーズ発生したのですが「%SystemRoot%\MEMORY.DMP」のダンプファイル更新日時は2日前のままでした。原因として何か考えられることはありますか？

Comment: フリーズの場合は、ダンプ ファイルは生成されません。
なので自力でシステム クラッシュさせ、ブルースクリーンを発生させる必要があります。
つまり、(一番初め返信にも書きましたが) フリーズ現象を発生させ、そのタイミングでシステム クラッシュさせることで、ブルースクリーンよる完全メモリダンプを採取する、ということです。
問題は、ハング時にどうやって自力でシステム クラッシュさせるのか。。。ですが、従来より Windows のキーボード ドライバにはブルースクリーンを発生させる機能が実装されているので、その機能を使えばハング時でも簡単にクラッシュさせることができます。
詳しくは、以下のサイトの「(7) キーボードを使用したメモリ ダンプ生成方法」を参照してください。
(なお、キーボード クラッシュの設定は、残念ながらレジストリの設定が必須になります。)
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcorejp/2014/08/10/339/

Comment: 「フリーズ現象を発生させ、そのタイミングでシステム クラッシュさせることで、ブルースクリーンよる完全メモリダンプを採取する」。なるほど、そういう意味だったのですね。読解力が足りませんでした。また、リンク提示ありがとうございます！ ごのページを初めて知りました(かなり検索したつもりですが全く気が付きませんでした…)

Comment: 私、stackoverflow で返信したのはじめてで、全くの初心者なのでアレなんですけど。。。
現在
「長時間におよぶディスカッションをコメントで行うことは避けてください。自動的にこのディスカッションをチャットに移動させますか？」
と表示され、なんか怒られてるみたいなんですけど、これってどーすればいいんですか？

Answer (score 1):

オイラん部署で突然不調になった PC の話をするなら、メモリの故障でした。
別の PC の不調は CPU ヒートシンクの密着不良でした。
ダンプ解析なんて面倒なことする前にハードウエア側不良を疑って memtest86+ 等の診断ソフトを実行してみることをお勧めします。

[インテルプロセッサ診断ツール](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/ja/download/19792/Intel-Processor-Diagnostic-Tool)
[memtest86+](https://www.memtest.org/)
CPU 温度測定ツール各種

memtest86+ はたいていの Linux の LiveCD に入っているはず。

Comment: インテルプロセッサ診断ツールを試したところ、結果はPASSでした。memtest86+をUSBから起動させようと試みたのですが、「BIOSセットアップ画面」も「起動メニュー」も正常動作しないことが分かりました。具体的には、「F1」「F12」何れをクリックしても、黒い画面へ遷移します

Comment: 起動メニューが表示できるようになったので(理由不明)、memtest86+を試してみました。まだ1回しか終わっていませんが、Errorsは0でした

Comment: Windows Vista以降であれば[Windowsメモリ診断](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1810/01/news015.html)が付属しているので、ソフトウェアを別途しなくてもテストできます。

Comment: Windowsメモリ診断を試してみました。エラーは検出されませんでした